# ASP.Net core добавить заголовки и переадресовать

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Я хочу в контроллере добавить заголовок и переадресовать запрос к иному контроллу. Дулаю это следующим образом:

```
Responce.Headders.Add("Key", "Value");
Responce.Redirect("/NewAdress");
```

Но когда происходит переадресация, запрос приходит без заголовка что я добавил. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, сам когда-то хотел спросить.

Comment: Три опечатки в коде из 2 строк, это случайно, или так надо?

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Этот вопрос не о каком-то фреймворке типа asp.net core (типа, плохой фреймворк, не умеет) или php -- а просто нужно хорошо понимать как работает протокол http.

Ну вот вам первая попавшаяся [цитата c stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218304/5752652):

> It's impossible to redirect to a page with custom headers set, no matter what language or framework you use. In other words, there's no way to trigger an HTTP redirect and cause the client (browser) to add a custom header.

Вы можете либо создать новый HttpClient и в нём дёрнуть НОВЫЙ запрос (да, понимаю, что вы думаете что это как-то избыточно), можете передать параметры в другой контроллер не используя доп. заголовки ОДНОВРЕМЕННО с редиректом, можете переделать своё приложение, чтобы общий для нескольких контроллеров код вынести в общие классы... но вот именно в такой форме задача не решается.

А, вот вам [ещё лучше объяснение](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) от компании производящей хорошие браузеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут в чём вся соль? В том, что делается ДРУГОЙ запрос и заголовки от предыдущего не используются, веб-сервер в этом плане ведёт себя как браузер.

В вашем вопросе под словом "заголовки" смешиваются "заголовки ответа" (серверные) и "заголовки запроса" (клиентские): устанавливаете заголовки ОТВЕТА (просьба сменить header: location), и ставите заголовки ожидая что это будут заголовки а) запроса причём б) НОВОГО.